# Why does improfile produce noisy plots?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have images at this link: https://imgur.com/a/i0vB9

I am trying to take a line profile of the 2nd white line in the 1st image in that link, using `improfile`

I ran `improfile(Ic, xc, yc, 50);` using `yc = [20 140]`. The 2nd image in that link I used `xc = [20 30]` and for the 3rd image I used `xc = [20 80]`

This doesn't make sense to me as I would expect the plot to more closely resemble a smooth plot (such as the 4th image in the link) as you increase the size of `xc`. Because I thought if you increase the width of `x`, there should be less noise for a given value for `y`. For example, if at `y=20`, `x=20` would produce 1 value for `I` at `y=20`. But if you expand `x` at `y=20`, so that there is `x=20, 21, 22, 23, 24`, then there would be 5 `I` values at the given `y=20`, so the reported value for `I` at `y=20` would be the average of those 5 `I` values, right?

Other than blurring the image, isn't there a way to get `improfile` to generate smoother plots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`improfile` returns the value of the image at equally spaced points between start and end points. In your case, `start=[xc(1),yc(1)]`, and `end=[xc(2),yc(2)]`.

I think that what you are trying to do is this:

```
mean(Ic(yc(1):yc(2),xc(1):xc(2)),2)
```

There, I extract a rectangular region from the image, and average along the x-axis. This gives me a plot similar to yours, but much smoother. And the larger `xc(2)` is, the smoother it becomes:

[image]

(blue: `xc=[20,30]`, red: `xc=[20,80]`)

---

An alternative approach would be to smooth the image in the direction perpendicular to the profile you want to extract. This is easy if the profile to be extracted is horizontal or vertical, as in your case (e.g. a simple convolution along rows or columns only), but requires specialized filters for profiles in other directions.

Answer (score 0):

An easy thing to do, if you have some prior about the smoothness constraints you'd like to impose on the profile, would be to just post-process the profile.

For example:

```
p = improfile(Ic, xc, yc, 50);
pnew = conv(p,ones(1,9)/9,'valid');
```

Where here we're just applying an ideal low pass averaging filter along the profile and discarding the first and last 4 points in the profile. You could filter p however you want.

Comment: that does produce a smoother plot. However, `x=[20 80]` is still not noticeably smoother than `x=[20 30]`: https://imgur.com/a/KEqNI